# Add subview from nib or programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios

Just a concept question.
What would you prefer doing and why, should you need to insert into a view a subview, would you rather have a nib file to add it or would you programatically insert it?
I am talking about xcode 4.~ development using storyboards.

Regards, Guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your situation. If it's something very simple or something dynamic (variable number of buttons for example) then I would do it programmatically. If it's a complex but static view (something like a settings view) then I would try using IB.

Comment: Saying it is dynamic, wouldn't it still be easier to implement with the IB?
Currently, I am doing it programmatically and it works well ... just been wondering, as you can do the same thing in a million ways when you're iOS developing ...

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? You can't define dynamic interfaces in IB.

Comment: A subview who only takes a part of the screen with a view buttons and the background set to clearcolor for example, a pop up of some sort for example.
Is that dynamic enough? or am I missing the point?

Comment: That doesn't sound dynamic to me. With dynamic I mean a layout that you can't predict at compile time. For instance a variable number of buttons, based on a setting of the user. You can't do something like this in IB as you would have to load X number of buttons using a `for` loop.

Comment: Well saying the popup is popping in a location based on the user click, that is dynamic. But can't you do it with a xib file?

Comment: You can create the (static) GUI of the popup in a xib. But to actually load and show it at the desired (dynamic) location you have to use code.

Answer (score 2):

I personally will do it **programmatically** if i need the view to be **dynamic**. But it can be done even with the view created in the xib file. I would prefer **creating in xib** if the the view needs **no dynamism** so that it would **reduce my coding portion**

Comment: A xib file will not let it be dynamic?

Comment: it will let it be dynamic, but i feel convenient to do it programmatically

Comment: so you can't see any pros/cons directly related to programmatically or xib.
I feel more convenient programming it as well.

Comment: the only pros i see is that if you do it in xib file it will reduce your coding protion